# Passing variable to VBA event handler after execution

Tags: vba, ms-access, events

How do I pass a variable to an event in VBA, when the event occurs after execution of my method/sub?

In Detail:

```
'My Sub''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Sub mySub()
   structCalculateDateValues 'calculates a number of dates that I want to be unlocked on my form
   fnCreateTable  'create a table will all dates form my database
End Sub

'Event handler for continous form'''''''''''''''
Private Sub Form_Current()
   'Some code to get the value of my Struct - structCalculateDateValues
   'Lock records that do not fall within of the date parameters of the values in structCalculateDateValues 
End Sub
```

The concept here is I want a form to show a record for all dates in a temp table, but only allow some of those records to be editable. This takes place in MS Access 2013.  The way I have it set up is:

1. Create a struct containing all date calculation
2. Load values into temp table based on those calculations
3. A continuous form that is bound to that table already exists
4. Execution would normally end here
5. As the form open it triggers the Form_Current Event Handler
6. Pass struct values to that handler somehow??????

This is more a question of efficiency than anything else and a big question is how that event is triggered. I also want to avoid an answer that results in me writing my struct member values to the database (would be a cop-out).  I think there has to be a way in VBA to pause execution to detect an event right?

Thanks,

Comment: set it as a module variable where my sub is private myStruct as xyz then assign and use. use structCalculateDateValues  as a function with a return of your struct also maybe

Comment: If I understand this you are suggesting that I recalculate my Struct in the event handler.  This is easy to do yes, and my struct is a module set up like you suggest.  However, i'd like to save my  processor the effort if possible.  Essentially i'd be duplicating work (if I'm understanding you here).

Comment: so just use it, if you have private struct at the top, then you can use in current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a *module-level* variable. That way you can access it from anywhere within the module:

```
Option Explicit
Private MyValue As MyValueType '<---

Private Sub Some_ParameterlessEventHandler()
    MyValue.SomeMember = 42
End Sub

Private Sub SomeProcedureThatRunsAfterTheHandler()
    Debug.Print MyValue.SomeMember 'outputs 42
End Sub
```

Comment: Won't a global or module level variable be lost to garbage collection?  I believe in VBA after my Main Sub ends the references are released and all variables are garbage collected, correct?  Also, I don't have free rein with the event handlers concerning a continuous form.  They are in a separate module inside their own access object.

Comment: VBA does no garbage collection, it's reference-counted, and it won't "reset" until the `End` keyword is encountered or your macro bursts into flames.

Comment: @JamieMarshall note: by `End` I mean the actual `End` instruction, not the `End` part of the `End Sub` token. As long as the host application is alive, module variables live, unless you kill 'em with the `End` nuke.

Comment: Your solution works!  I'm surprised.  What references still exist to keep a variable alive where there is no code execution within the module?  Thanks by the way.

Comment: It's just "there", sitting in global space - the execution context remains "alive" until you kill it with `End` (either in code or in the immediate pane - not sure pressing the 'Stop' button does the same, but it's possible), or until the host application exits.